# How to get parameter type from javax.lang.model.VariableElement

Tags: java, apt

I'm trying to find the types of the parameters of a method using the Java 6 metamodel API. If the type is an enum, 
I'd also like to know all of it's type's enum constant names. Here's what I've got so far:

```
for (Element member : members) {
    if(member.getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD) {
        ExecutableElement methodElement = (ExecutableElement) member;
        List<? extends VariableElement> parameters = methodElement.getParameters();
        for (VariableElement parameter : parameters) {
            //How do I get the type of the parameter here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Element#asType()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#asType%28%29) gets you the DeclaredType.

For enums, use [Types#asElement()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html) with the DeclaredType to get the enum type's element, and then iterate over the members using either an ElementVisitor or by using getEnclosedElements().

Comment: It worked, though I can't help but feel like this is one of the least intuitive APIs I've worked with.