# Get class name and package of VariableElement

Tags: java

I have a `VariableElement` object `ve` (which I got from getting the parameters of an `ExecutableElement` object) at compile time in an annotations processor (in the `process()` method). The class represented by this `VariableElement` object can be different in different cases.

How can I get the full package and classname as a string of `ve` at compile time?

(e.g. if `ve` represents a parameter which is of class `String`, I need to get the string `"java.lang.String"`)

edit: based on the answers so far, it seems I have not been clear enough. `ve` is not a `String` object, but is actually a `VariableElement` object which represents a parameter element inside a method call (`ExecutableElement`). I need to get information about what is being represented by the `VariableElement ve` (specifically what the class information is about the class of the parameter), rather than the `ve` object itself.

Comment: `String name = ve.getClass().getName();`

Comment: YCF_L your code snippet doesn't get the class of what's inside the `VariableElement` object, but the class of the `VariableElement` itself

Comment: Might this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763311/how-to-get-parameter-type-from-javax-lang-model-variableelement ?

Comment: Have you tried looking into `asType()` and then use the TypeMirror's `toString()`?

Comment: @mroman your answer worked! Post an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `VariableElement`s `asType()` method to get a `TypeMirror` object and then the `toString()` method should return a "source code" representation of the type. There's also some utility function in `Types` that can be used with `TypeMirror`s.